# How can I store a character (literal number) into an int array in C?

Tags: c

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if((c >= '0') && (c <= '9')) {
        ndigits[length] = c;
        length = length + 1;
    }
}
```

I want to store each digit, in the array. But when I enter `123` and print the array, I get `50 51 52`. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Store `c - '0'`

Comment: You should be getting `49, 50, 51`.

Comment: Also, use the `isdigit()` function instead of testing the range yourself.

Comment: @Barmar I don't agree; `isdigit` is a bug trap. If you pass it certain values that can legitimately come from `getchar`, the behavior is undefined. The odds of newbies getting this right the first time without hand-holding from a mentor are low.

Comment: `if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') ndigits[length++] = c - '0';`  There is no need to have multiple statements in this `if`, if we apply the standard C idiom of post-incrementing `length`.

Comment: @Kaz: What exactly do you mean? Are you talking about return values of `getchar` being converted to `char` before being passed on to `isdigit`? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I have misspoken in this particular case, since `getchar` should be returning values in the range 0 to `UCHAR_MAX`. (Except on some DSP chip or something where `sizeof (int)` is 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Characters are numbers too. In this case, you have ASCII codes, or at least the ASCII subset of UTF-8 encoded Unicode code points. The integer `'1'` is indeed 49, `'2'` is 50, etc. When you store them in your array, it stores the numerical value of the ASCII code for that number. If you want the number itself, you can do something like:

```
if((c >= '0') && (c <= '9'))
{
    ndigits[length] = c - '0';
    length = length + 1;
}
```

Comment: 'Thank you that work. But why " - '0' " ?

Comment: @CristhoferLugo. Because that's the first one.

Comment: @CristhoferLugo {48, 49, 50, ....} are {'0', '1', '2', ...}, so if you subtract '0', you get {0, 1, 2, ...}